# How to update the data of the second axes plotly javascript?

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

Here is the code:

```js
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3],
  y: [40, 50, 60],
  name: 'yaxis data',
  type: 'scatter'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [2, 3, 4],
  y: [4, 5, 6],
  name: 'yaxis2 data',
  yaxis: 'y2',
  type: 'scatter'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];

var layout = {
  title: 'Double Y Axis Example',
  yaxis: {title: 'yaxis title'},
  yaxis2: {
    title: 'yaxis2 title',
    titlefont: {color: 'rgb(148, 103, 189)'},
    tickfont: {color: 'rgb(148, 103, 189)'},
    overlaying: 'y',
    side: 'right'
  }
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<head><script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script></head>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

I just want to update the data on the second axes `yaxis2`. I want to avoid the data redundancy, hence I do not want to forward the other data.

Please let me know what I can do.

Comment: Is there no one who can help me with the javascript queries? I had different queries but none replied to them. Even this query is still not active I guess. Please I request you all to help me with this at least.

Comment: Are you trying to change `trace2` to something else, and re-plotting the data, while not replotting the data in `trace1`?

Comment: @KevinBai Yes. And I do not want to pass the trace1 next time once I have plotted it.

Comment: looking at plot.ly's documentation, `Plot.react` https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyreact  allows you to update by passing in a new array and doing a diff (so it won't redraw unchanged data). You could also use `Plot.removeTrace` then, `Plot.addTrace` to remove the data and readd it.

Comment: @KevinBai Thank you for the reference,but can you show it to me how it will work in my case? If possible then please use my example and give a demo as answer. It will help everyone who is visiting this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `Plotly.react`, or `Plotly.addTraces`/`Plotly.deleteTraces`. Here are the [docs](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference).

In order to update the data, you can't mutate the data. You need to create a new immutable instance of the data ([reference](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyreact)).

So you can either make a copy of data and by:

```
Plotly.react('myDiv', data.map((trace, i) => {
  if (i != 1) return trace;
  return <new trace>
})
```

Or, you could remove a trace and re-add it:

```
const newTrace = {...} // some trace object
Plotly.deleteTraces('myDiv', 1); // remove at index 1
Plotly.addTraces('myDiv', newTrace);
```

Below is an example of updating the plot after a 1 second timeout:

```js
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3],
  y: [40, 50, 60],
  name: 'yaxis data',
  type: 'scatter'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [2, 3, 4],
  y: [4, 5, 6],
  name: 'yaxis2 data',
  yaxis: 'y2',
  type: 'scatter'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];

var layout = {
  title: 'Double Y Axis Example',
  yaxis: {title: 'yaxis title'},
  yaxis2: {
    title: 'yaxis2 title',
    titlefont: {color: 'rgb(148, 103, 189)'},
    tickfont: {color: 'rgb(148, 103, 189)'},
    overlaying: 'y',
    side: 'right'
  }
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);

setTimeout(() => {
  const newTrace = {
    x: [2, 3, 4],
    y: [4, 10, 20],
    name: 'yaxis2 data',
    yaxis: 'y2',
    type: 'scatter'
  }
  // delete the second trace (index 1) or delete multiple traces with Plotly.deleteTraces('myDiv', [0,1])
  Plotly.deleteTraces('myDiv', 1); 
  // add a new trace
  Plotly.addTraces('myDiv', newTrace);
}, 1000)
```

```html
<head><script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script></head>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you .. I will try it later. But I guess this is what will be helpful.